# How to display application logs in Console.app from a sandbox application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, sandbox

In sandbox, app writes log files to location in its own container like (~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Logs/Notes).

I need the console app to show my application logs by default.

Please let me know how this can be achieved